# This nuance of 理解ありすぎ

Tags: reading-comprehension

Context: The character revealed she got together with her crush to her best friend, and the best friends screams at her this:

> 全然納得いかない *I can't accept this*

> なんで付き合うんだよ *Why are you going out with them?*

and then

> まじやめろって! いくら　優しいからってさぁ。。。んな簡単にお前となんて理解ありすぎだろ！

I understand

> 優しいからってさぁ。。。んな簡単にお前となんて

Is akin "no matter how kind he is... doing something like going with out with you is...

However I'm struggling with 理解ありすぎだろ. My reading from context would be akin "they are far too understanding"?

Comment: 'going out with them?' Is *them* referring to the crush? Why plural?

Comment: @sundowner It is so called ["singular they"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) phenomenon, which is used as gender-neutral third-person pronoun and is attested for many centuries. In situations when gender-neutrality is required, I personally prefer spelling "he/she"...

Comment: @Arfrever If so, it is not consistent with the *how kind he is...* afterwards.

Comment: @sundowner By the way, Japanese [彼]{か​れ} originally was also gender-neutral "he/she". In 19th century, under European influence, meaning of [彼](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/彼#Japanese) shifted to "he" and [彼女](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/彼女) was invented for "she". In Mandarin since 1910s, pronoun *tā* = /tʰä⁵⁵/ has artificial distinction in writing only: [他](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/他#Chinese) for "he", [她](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/她#Chinese) for "she", [牠](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/牠#Chinese)／[它](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/它#Chinese) for "it" and 祂 for deities.

Answer (score 2):

[理解がある](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E7%90%86%E8%A7%A3%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase meaning "have understanding", and すぎ after a verb/adjective means "over(ly)" or "excessive(ly)". Xに理解がありすぎる means someone is showing too much understanding toward X.

This kind of question has to be assessed along with the entire context (and the pictures if this is from a manga), but it seems likely that you have misunderstood the implicit subject of these sentences. Since the only explicit personal pronoun here says お前**と** "(dating) you", the implicit subject should be not "you" but "her crush".

Does the following make sense to you? (I guess this speaker was too excited and said やめろ as if "he" were present.)

> なんで付き合うんだよ
> Why is **he** going out with **you**?
>
> まじやめろって! いくら優しいからってさぁ… んな簡単に「**お前と**」なんて理解ありすぎだろ！
> Seriously, **he** needs to stop this! No matter how kind **he** is, it's way too generous of **him** to start dating someone like **you** easily!

Comment: I see. My reading of  まじやめろ was "You need to stop this" since the friend was talking to the protagonist and obviously they agreed to start dating.

The "he/boyfriend" is not in the scene.

Comment: @Kawase_K Can you paste the actual scene? I can't say anything for sure without seeing the actual page.